# Split a dynamic range into equal parts using js

Tags: javascript, numbers

So the problem I'm tackling involves getting a dynamic range and splitting it into 6 parts.

For example a range can start from 6.1 and end at 93.6. Or as simple as 6-24.

At the end, what i am trying to do is to just get 6 different points in that range. If it's 1-24, that would be 4,8,12,16,20,24.

Here is an approach that I am using with not quite accurate results:

```
const range = {start: '', end: ''};
const offset = Math.ceil(range.end / 6);

const markers = []
for(let i = offset; i <= range.end; i++){
  if(range.end % i == 0){
    markers.push(i)
  }
}
console.log(markers);
```

Comment: And what is the problem you're encountering with this?

Comment: @devlincarnate the problem of how to approach it, are you kind enough to have a solution I can use?

Comment: Have you tried dividing the number of possible numbers in the range by 6?  So, in the case of 1-24, there are 24 numbers in the range.  24 / 6 = 4, which gives you your offset.  Of course, you'll have to account for precision but you haven't specified what should happen when you have something other than a whole number that divides evenly by 6.

Comment: Is your trouble to calculate iteration step? `var step = (maxVal - minVal)/6`? Or is it difficult to make 6 iterations to fill array? Just begin from `minValue` and then increase variable value by `step`.

Comment: please add a comprehensible example.

Comment: Why do you divide the empty **string** by 6?!

Comment: Thanks guys for your helpful feedback. I have added some code, which is in need of improvement. For example if i use a range of 1-25, I get [ 6, 8, 12, 24 ]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For six parts, you need five offsets. This offset is calculated by the delta of left and right divided by parts minus one.

Then iterate until all smaller parts are taken, at the end take the right value without any calculation to prevent floating point arithmetic errors.

```js
function split(left, right, parts) {
    var result = [],
        delta = (right - left) / (parts - 1);
    while (left < right) {
        result.push(left);
        left += delta;
    }
    result.push(right);
    return result;
}

console.log(split(6, 24, 6));
console.log(split(6.1, 93.6, 6));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var start = parseFloat(Math.random() * 10);
var end = parseFloat(Math.random() * 100);

var diff = ((end - start) / 6);
console.log("Start: ", start)
for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
  start += parseFloat(diff);
  console.log(start);
}
console.log("End: ", end);
```

Hope this will help you start the work.